# Предзагрузка сайта как на youtube

Tags: javascript, node.js

Каким образом на ютубе реализована такая предзагрузка? Сложно ли такое сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же на твиче

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: skeleton loading component загугли, вот неплохой пример: https://css-tricks.com/building-skeleton-screens-css-custom-properties/

Comment: @SultanovShamil То что надо! Спасибо

Comment: @SultanovShamil будет неплохо если оформите ответ с подробным описанием и кодом - примером